# Using Protractor to check for a value that is visible

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a section of code that displays two different ways based on a condition. In both ways, there is a value that I want to check:

```
user.name
```

This is displayed on the page like

```
<span ng-show="showusername && something > 3">{{user.name}} (other stuff here)</span>
<span ng-show="showusername && something <= 3">{{user.name}}</span>
```

My problem is, this is used elsewhere on the page as well, and the protractor piece can't seem to find the binding if I use by.binding('user.name'), it finds multiple, and displays

```
Expected ''  to equal 'Joe Smith'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [filter](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) out the *visible* elements only:

```
var visibleUserNames = element.all(by.binding("user.name")).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
         return isDisplayed;
    });
});
expect(visibleUserNames.count()).toEqual(1);
expect(visibleUserNames.first().getText()).toEqual("Joe Smith");
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know about the filter function, works perfect.